# How to share a single GPU deep learning server?

Tags: python, tensorflow, server, deep-learning, architecture

For our development team we want to build a central GPU server for their deep learning / training tasks (with one or more strong GPU(s) instead of mulitple workstations for each team member with their own GPU). I guess this is a common setup, but I am not sure how to make this GPU sharing work for multiple team members simultaneously. We work with Tensorflow/Keras and Python scripts.

My question is: What is the typical approach to let team members train their models on that central server? Just allow them to access via SSH and do network training directly from command line? Or setup a Jupyter Hub server, so that our developers can run code from their browser?

My main question: If there is only one GPU, how can we make sure that multiple users cannot run their code (i.e. train their networks) at the same time? Is there a way to kind of submit training jobs on a central server software and those are executed on the GPU one after the other?

(Sorry if this is not the correct site to ask this question, but which other Stack Exchange site would be better?)

Comment: Try to look into pcluster or slurm for single GPU case. Kubernetes would be another technology to look into

Comment: Have you found any viable solutions?

Comment: @AtifAli Not really, we ended up buying a large machine with 4 GPUs as addition to our smaller office machine with only one GPU.

Comment: And how are you sharing the resources for your new 4 GPU machine? If 2 users need access at the same time? how do you split CPUs, RAM, and storage? so that one user can not affect the other?

Comment: @AtifAli We wrote a custom Torch/Keras training wrapper, that manages all our images and videos, creates training&validation data out of that and queues all our training jobs, so that the system would start these training jobs one after the other using all 4 GPUs on each job ...

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am just looking to share a single server that has 2 GPUs with  other lab members.

Comment: @AtifAli See my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though we don't need this setup any more, one option to solve this is via a workload manager like [slurm](https://slurm.schedmd.com/). There is also [GPU management](https://slurm.schedmd.com/gres.html#GPU_Management) available.